# How do I Add Distinctive Blocks of Form Controls Using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am doing a small human resource web application in my workplace and i have a CV section were employees can add their CVs to be displayed to the human resource manager.

I want to make something similar to what [Stackoverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) has done in the **Experience** and **Education** sections where the users can click the "**add more experience**" or "**add more education**" links for new form elements to appear and a **remove**, **move up** and/or **move down** links appear.

I think that this was possible using jQuery and either the **append** or **appendTo** functions. That's as much as I know about jQuery and have no idea on how to go about implementing that.

The solution that i require should:

- Enable me to add a template one for
  the Experience section and the other
  for Education
- On the loading of the page at least
  one education section and one
  Experience section appears on the
  form
- Form controls must have an
  identifying value added to them to
  distinct them from other sections.
  For instance, when the page first
  appears each form control should end
  with 0, when the **add more** button
  is clicked, each form control's name
  should end with 1, and so on.
- Some sort of validaion

I am using ASP.NET WebForms if such information is needed.

Thanks,,

Comment: Anything else you'd like us to do while we're at it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for you to write the code on my behalf. But could you please guide me to articles or code snippets that may help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know how to code C# / .NET.
Make the code which dispays CV.

Then start learning jQuery by going here: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works
Understand jQuery, and things will get less complicated.